In this sentence: 今の所九人ぐらいが来ると思います。 is the が needed? And if not why?
I asked a native speaker and they said the が is not necessary but they don't know why. Is it because ぐらい can replace particles? If that is the case, which particles does ぐらい replace?

ぐらい can replace a particle, but in this case, you don't need が even if ぐらい is not used. Note that "omitting が" is not a correct phrase here; removing が changes the basic structure of the sentence.
The following sentences are both valid, but the former sounds more idiomatic:

9人来ると思います。
(super-literally) I think people will come in (a group of) nine.
9人が来ると思います。
I think nine people will come.

This is because a word like 9人 can work adverbially in Japanese. See:

How to list numbers of things
Positioning of quantities (using counters)

